# Play a list of songs with media player on WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms, media-player

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        string[] nomi, percorsi; //nomi means names and percorsi means paths. I'm italian, that's why

        private void apri_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog apri = new OpenFileDialog();
            apri.Filter = "File *.mp3|*.mp3";
            apri.Multiselect = true;
            DialogResult scelta = apri.ShowDialog();
            if (scelta == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                nomi = apri.SafeFileNames;
                percorsi = apri.FileNames;
                for (int i = 0; i < nomi.Length; i++)
                    Files.Items.Add(nomi[i]);
            }
        }

        private void Files_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            player.URL = percorsi[Files.SelectedIndex];
        }
    }
}
```

I have this code to create a simple mp3 player. Is there a wayy to enable the previous/next buttons on the media player and play the next/previous song in the listbox? And also is there a way to find if the song ended so that I can play the next one? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly is in your form?

Comment: @Ilan321 A media player, a button to trigger the openFileDialog and a listbox to contain the file names

Answer (score 0):

```
private void player_PlayStateChange(object sender, AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEvent e)
{
    if (e.newState == 8)
    {
    }
}
```

Found a solution. I'll post it so maybe it will help someone else. e.newState == 8 is true if the song is finished, so then I can start playing the next song.